# If $\sqrt{(x-1)^2}+\sqrt{(2-x)^2\ }-1=0$, then find all possible values of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L4s3.png)this was asked by my grade 11 math teacher yesterday. Seems like a good question.

It clearly can't be solved by removing the squares since the x cancels out and I am left with 0=0. Wolfram Alpha gave the answer but not the solution

Comment: It is incorrect to say that the $x$ cancels out (well , not always) as $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$..

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is any value of $x$ between 1 and 2 inclusive. Yes you **can** remove the squares, but you have to be careful of the cases where one or the other values becomes negative. So you need to consider the three regions $x>2$, $x<1$ and $x\in[1,2]$ separately. Because both roots give a positive value, it's obvious that there are no solutions where the value of $x-1$ exceeds 1 in the region $x>2$, and similarly $|2-x|$ exceeds 1 in the region $x<1$, so the only region left is $[1,2]$, and in this region you can cancel.

Comment: can you please provide a detailed solution for this cuz when i put the value         1<x<2, i end up with x-1+2-x-1=0 where the x cancels out again

Comment: Yes, you've got it. Any value of $x$ from 1 to 2 satisfies the equation. Re-read my answer before asking again.

Comment: OK, I understand, just explain to me what you mean by ''and in this region you can cancel''

Comment: As you said in the top comment, in this region $x-1+2-x=1$, the $x$s **cancel** each other out. OK?

Answer (score 1):

Using $\sqrt{t^2}=|t|$, we have $|x-1|+|2-x|=1=|(x-1)+(2-x)|$. Now, from the triangle inequality, $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ with equality when $ab\geq 0$ (same sign, or one of them is zero). Hence, $(x-1)(2-x)\geq 0$, whence $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: There is no need to use the triangle inequality or to multiply $(x-1)(2-x)$.

Comment: Why @SuzuHirose? It makes our calculations easier. Less work

Answer (score 1):

after making $\sqrt{(x-1)^2}+\sqrt{(2-x)^2}=|x-1|+|2-x|=1$ evaluate what happens when $x \in \langle -\infty, 1\rangle$ then evaluate $x \in [1,2]$ and finally $x \in \langle 2, \infty \rangle$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$ and not $u$. Also, to solve an equation with an absolute value in it you have to check both cases - where $|u|=u$ and $|u|=-u$. In your problem you will end up with two absolute values so you have four cases to check.

Comment: I don't think this answer/hint is correct, there are three regions to check and not four cases. Anyway when I saw this I wrote my own answer so please refer there.

Answer (score 0):

$y:=x-1;$

Equation $|y|+|1-y|=1;$

$1)|1-y|=1-|y| \ge 0;$

$-1 \le y \le 1;$

$2)|y|=1-|1-y| \ge 0;$

$-1 \le y-1 \le 1;$

$0 \le y \le 2;$

$3):$ $1)$ and $2):$

$0 \le y \le 1;$

4)Verify that

$0 \le y \le 1$ satisfies the equation.